# View shown after programmatically triggered segue doesn't update immediately

Tags: swift, ios10

I created two views and then connect one to the other by ctrl-dragging and creating a segue. Gave this segue the identifier "functionOutput1"

I then created a function and programmatically triggered the segue created above based on certain output in a function.

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "functionOuput1", sender: self)
```

The view segues okay but the contents of the view don't appear until a minute later.

Is there something else I need to be doing here?

EDIT:
I'm performing this segue in a callback function for a URLRequest

```
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
            data, response, error -> Void in

            if (error != nil) {
                // there is an error with the request
                print("error: ", error)

            } else {
                // Request was successful. Check the contents of the response.
                print("response: ", response)

                let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
                if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                    print("problems with server request")

                } else {
                    print("request successful")
                    //go to next page
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "functionOuput1", sender: self)
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a threading issue. Because the data is returned asynchronously. You need to run the view updates on the main thread. You can do this with Swift 3.0 with the following code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // Your view updates here                
}
```

Comment: Absolutely works! Re-learning iOS programming here so appreciate the quick response. Is using "self." safe in that async block?

Comment: Glad that it worked! Yeah the usage of self in async block is safe.